# How to store the nested json which is in a list to a text file using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-jsonschema

I am creating a nested json and i am storing it in a list object. Here is my code which is getting the proper hierarchical json as intended.

Sample Data:

[image]

datasource,datasource_cnt,category,category_cnt,subcategory,subcategory_cnt
    Bureau of Labor Statistics,44,Employment and wages,44,Employment and wages,44

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('queryhive16273.csv')
def split_df(df):
   for (vendor, count), df_vendor in df.groupby(["datasource", "datasource_cnt"]):
       yield {
           "vendor_name": vendor,
           "count": count,
           "categories": list(split_category(df_vendor))
       }

def split_category(df_vendor):
   for (category, count), df_category in df_vendor.groupby(
       ["category", "category_cnt"]
   ):
       yield {
           "name": category,
           "count": count,
           "subCategories": list(split_subcategory(df_category)),
       }

def split_subcategory(df_category):
   for (subcategory, count), df_subcategory in df_category.groupby(
       ["subcategory", "subcategory_cnt"]
   ):
       yield {
           "count": count,
           "name": subcategory,
             }


abc=list(split_df(df))
```

abc is containing the data as shown below. This is the intended result.

```
[{
    'count': 44,
    'vendor_name': 'Bureau of Labor Statistics',
    'categories': [{
        'count': 44,
        'name': 'Employment and wages',
        'subCategories': [{
            'count': 44,
            'name': 'Employment and wages'
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Now I am trying to store it into a json file.

```
with open('your_file2.json', 'w') as f:
    for item in abc:
       f.write("%s\n" % item)
        #f.write(abc)
```

Here comes the issue. This writes data in this fashion( refer below) which is not a valid json format. If i try to use json dump, it gives "json serialize error"

Could you please help me out here.

```
{
    'count': 44,
    'vendor_name': 'Bureau of Labor Statistics',
    'categories': [{
        'count': 44,
        'name': 'Employment and wages',
        'subCategories': [{
            'count': 44,
            'name': 'Employment and wages'
        }]
    }]
}
```

Expected Result :

```
[{
    "count": 44,
    "vendor_name": "Bureau of Labor Statistics",
    "categories": [{
        "count": 44,
        "name": "Employment and wages",
        "subCategories": [{
            "count": 44,
            "name": "Employment and wages"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Do not print JSON by yourself (DRTW), it is not a good idea, use encoder instead. In this case the standard breaks because you print out single quote instead of double.

Comment: Is there an answer that fit your request? If so, you should mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your data and PSL `json` gives me:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable
```

Which just means some numpy object is living in your nested structure and does not have an `encode` method to convert it for JSON serialization.

Forcing encode to use string conversion when it lacks in the object itself is enough to make your code works:

```
import io
d = io.StringIO("datasource,datasource_cnt,category,category_cnt,subcategory,subcategory_cnt\nBureau of Labor Statistics,44,Employment and wages,44,Employment and wages,44")
df=pd.read_csv(d)

abc=list(split_df(df))

import json
json.dumps(abc, default=str)
```

It returns a valid JSON (but with `int` converted into `str`):

```
'[{"vendor_name": "Bureau of Labor Statistics", "count": "44", "categories": [{"name": "Employment and wages", "count": "44", "subCategories": [{"count": "44", "name": "Employment and wages"}]}]}]'
```

If it does not suit your needs, then use a dedicated [Encoder](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders):

```
import numpy as np
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.int64):
            return int(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

json.dumps(abc, cls=MyEncoder)
```

This returns the requested JSON:

```
'[{"vendor_name": "Bureau of Labor Statistics", "count": 44, "categories": [{"name": "Employment and wages", "count": 44, "subCategories": [{"count": 44, "name": "Employment and wages"}]}]}]'
```

Another option is to directly convert your data before encoding:

```
def split_category(df_vendor):
   for (category, count), df_category in df_vendor.groupby(
       ["category", "category_cnt"]
   ):
       yield {
           "name": category,
           "count": int(count), # Cast here before encoding
           "subCategories": list(split_subcategory(df_category)),
       }
```

Comment: how to write these to a text file ? Could you please write that line in your json.dump

Comment: @ShankarPanda Just use `dump` instead of `dumps` as @Buran did in its answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

data = [{
    'count': 44,
    'vendor_name': 'Bureau of Labor Statistics',
    'categories': [{
        'count': 44,
        'name': 'Employment and wages',
        'subCategories': [{
            'count': 44,
            'name': 'Employment and wages'
        }]
    }]
}]

with open('your_file2.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

produces a valid JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "count": 44,
    "vendor_name": "Bureau of Labor Statistics",
    "categories": [
      {
        "count": 44,
        "name": "Employment and wages",
        "subCategories": [
          {
            "count": 44,
            "name": "Employment and wages"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This will not work with the trial dataset because it has `numpy.int64` instead of `int` within its structure. You skipped this part because you imported it as a Python structure not from the file.

Comment: @jlandercy I am using what OP is provided as abc value in their post. They say "abc is containing the data as shown below. This is the intended result.". I don't see where do you get any other trial dataset. Clearly their problem is because they iterate over the list and write each element as text in a simple txt file and produce invalid json.

Comment: Look to my answer, I did find the relevant data in the OP. You solution will not work with its dataset: copy paste StringIO and you will be able to reproduce the issue. This does not mean your answer is wrong, it just will not solve OP issue.

Comment: @jlandercy, I see it now - it's because they use pandas to read csv in a dataframe. Eventually they can convert `count` to int when yield and it should solve the issue

Comment: Yes, this where `numpy.int64` comes from, already suggested. Have a good day.